# Uncomment sonar.properties file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I need to uncomment and append few lines in Sonar.properties files using shell script. Below script has few issues. Please help me. the issue is first two lines of code is appending but third line is not uncommenting the same.

```
sed -i 's/#sonar.jdbc.username=/sonar.jdbc.username=sonar/g' /opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties
sed -i 's/#sonar.jdbc.password=/sonar.jdbc.password=sonar/g' /opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties
sed -i 's/#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonarqube?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance=sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonarqube?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance/g' /opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties
```

Below is my sonar properties file

```
# Property values can:
# - reference an environment variable, for example sonar.jdbc.url= ${env:SONAR_JDBC_URL}
# - be encrypted. See http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/settings-encryption.html

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#
# IMPORTANT: the embedded H2 database is used by default. It is recommended for tests but not for
# production use. Supported databases are MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQLServer.

# User credentials.
# Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

#----- Embedded Database (default)
# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
#sonar.embeddedDatabase.port=9092


#----- MySQL 5.x
# Only InnoDB storage engine is supported (not myISAM).
# Only the bundled driver is supported. It can not be changed.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance


#----- Oracle 11g/12c
# - Only thin client is supported
# - Only versions 11.2.x and 12.x of Oracle JDBC driver are supported
# - The JDBC driver must be copied into the directory extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/
# - If you need to set the schema, please refer to http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE
```

Comment: Use Pipe as seperator instead of backlash

Comment: Why dou you have to _accept_ the answer and _unaccept_ it back? Did it work or not work?

Comment: Can you accept the solution back, if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do the line numbers change? If not, use addresses and just uncomment those lines:

```
sed -i '14,15,25s/#//' /opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties
```